# Transmitting and Receiving with 2 USRP N210

Tags: c++, signal-processing, usrp, uhd

I am very new to SDRs and with little background on DSP. I installed the uhd drivers and dependencies and can run/build the c++ examples. If I run tx_samples_from_file or tx_waveform at the TX end and run rx_samples_to_file at the RX end, I get random characters in the .dat file. Please what is the function of rx_samples_to_file? I thought rx_samples_to_file is supposed to get complex IQ sampled data equivalent of the received samples.

Eventually, what I would like to achieve with the USRPs is to generate random integers, map and modulate with say QAM or QPSK and transmit with the USRP TX and receive with USRP RX using a simple RF1 (back-to-back) connection.

Please help

Comment: Yes `rx_samples_to_file` stores the samples received, as IQ. Depending on the format you ask, each I and Q will use from 1 to 4 bytes. If you look at the content of the file, it will look like random characters, each I and Q corresponding to 1 to 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, You can find a lot of information about Ettus Research
hardware and software in *UHD Manual*, *Ettus Knowledge Base* and *USRP mailing list*.

I think that You can find solution to Your problem by consulting
application note ***Examples Provided with the USRP Hardware Driver*** (link is given below).

https://www.ettus.com/content/files/kb/application_note_uhd_examples.pdf

Ivan